# How to make a div placed from bottom to top

Tags: html, css

how to make the div placed from bottom to top and not from top to bottom.
For example this code places div from top to bottom

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
  <div class="message">
    <div class="message__block">4</div>
    <div class="message__block">3</div>
    <div class="message__block">2</div>
    <div class="message__block">1</div>
  </div>
</body>
</div>

<style>
  .message {
    width: 100vmin;
    height: 100vmin;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: green;
  }

  .message__block {
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 9vmin;
    background: black;
    margin-bottom: 1.1vmin;
  }
</style>

</body>

</html>
```

But how to make the divs are located from bottom to top as in this picture
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox).

```css
  .message {
    width: 100vmin;
    height: 100vmin;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: green;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .message__block {
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 9vmin;
    background: black;
    margin-bottom: 1.1vmin;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="message">
    <div class="message__block">4</div>
    <div class="message__block">3</div>
    <div class="message__block">2</div>
    <div class="message__block">1</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

---

If your `HTML` elements were in reverse order such as 1-4 and not 4-1 you could still achieve the same effect by changing the below properties like so:

```
justify-content: flex-start;
flex-direction: column-reverse;
```

Comment: I don't see how this reverses the order to ascending...

Comment: I just used the exact same HTML as from the question. If the HTML elements were in different order I would use `flex-direction: column-reverse;` to achieve the same effect.

Comment: I think he's asking how to reverse the order to asc

Comment: I have added a note to my answer to cover that possibility, thanks for pointing out @RobertRocha.

Comment: Hello, please tell me how can I use flex-shrink:0 in this example - I mean how can I make blocks that not shrink if they do not fit

Comment: I believe it would be all about adjusting the width of the elements but if you gave a better example, possibly in JSFiddle I could give you a definite answer. In general, you can read about `flex-shrink` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink You can see it comes in combination with `flex-basis`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
  <div class="message">
    <div class="message__block">4</div>
    <div class="message__block">3</div>
    <div class="message__block">2</div>
    <div class="message__block">1</div>
  </div>
</body>
</div>

<style>
  .message {
    width: 100vmin;
    height: 100vmin;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: green;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }

  .message__block {
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 9vmin;
    background: black;
    margin-bottom: 1.1vmin;
  }
</style>

</body>

</html>
```

CodePen:  https://codepen.io/Centaur26/pen/vYxKxMw

Make sure, display as flex,flex direction column reverse and justify-content flex-end.

Answer (score 1):

[image]Add the following to your .message class

```
height: auto;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `display` to `table-cell` and `vertical-align` to `bottom`, which provides [more support across browsers](https://caniuse.com/?search=table-cell) than [flexbox](https://caniuse.com/flexbox).

```css
.message {
  width: 100vmin;
  height: 100vmin;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: green;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}

.message__block {
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 9vmin;
  background: black;
  margin-bottom: 1.1vmin;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div class="message">
    <div class="message__block">4</div>
    <div class="message__block">3</div>
    <div class="message__block">2</div>
    <div class="message__block">1</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```